# Magento upgrade can't retrieve entity config: core/cache_option app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php

Tags: magento

I have upgraded my magento from 1.3 to 1.7.0.2 version. When try to access front end I am getting following error

```
Can't retrieve entity config: core/cache_option app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue. I was having the old version of `config.xml` (Magento 1.3 version ) file at following location `\app\etc` 
when I replaced this with the Magento 1.7.0.2 version's `\app\etc\config.xml` error gone.